# htaccess in laravel doesn't work

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-4, hosting

so i finished my project using Laravel 4.1 and when i tried to hosting it i got nothing, this is a picture from what i got :

[image]

this is my .**htaccss** code (inside public folder):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I think you should be trying to access the public directory or create a VHost to the public directory in AppName/public. Is it locally on on a server?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the directory and document root is pointed to the public folder in apache ie

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/public

<Directory /var/www/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```